# url friendly in yii framework do not work

Tags: yii

I am using ubuntu 12.04, and working for url friendly in yii framework, I follow these steps:
 
**step 1.** open the rewrite load modules by terminal

```
-sudo a2enmod rewrite
 -sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Loaded Modules in apache:

```
core mod_log_config mod_logio prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic 
mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user
mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_php5 
mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_status
```

**step 2:** create .htaccess and copy to project beside protected

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

**step 3:** open urlManager in main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',    
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'urlSuffix'=>'.html',                   
            'rules'=>array(         
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

but I have error url when access.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /news/news/index.html was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

project news and controller news

thankyou very much

Comment: have you tried the URL /news/index.html ? if it supposed to be /news/news/ you might need to rebase to /news/ in you're .htaccess file

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882089/remove-the-need-to-write-index-php-on-yii/20882173#20882173

Comment: Url can not run on localhost ?maybe I will set up new environment to run

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess needs to go in the same folder as where your index.php is and the servers' document root also needs to point to this folder. You should try that /news/index.php?r=news/index works on its own first.